# javac -version command not found error in rhel 7.3

Tags: rhel, java, openjdk

I followed [this documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openjdk/8/html/installing_and_using_openjdk_8_for_rhel/installing-openjdk8-on-rhel) to install `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.272.b10-1.portable.jdk.el.x86_64.tar.xz` into RHEL 7.3.

In section *2.4. Installing OpenJDK on RHEL using an archive*,
at the last step, *7.Verify that javac -version works without supplying the full path:*

```
$ javac -version
-bash: javac:command not found
```

I have appended the `.bashrc` file in the respective user account as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME=~/jres/java-8
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

The full path for `JAVA_HOME` was: `/home/myaccount/jres/java_8`

I also edited the `.bash_profile` inside the `/root` folder with the

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/myaccount/jres/java-8
```

This helped `root` account user receive a valid response when typing `echo $JAVA_HOME`. But it did not solve the java command not found issue.

Will appreciate any inputs to help.

Comment: When setting `JAVA_HOME`, did you give the path unquoted? Does it work if you replace `~` (tilde) by `$HOME`?  Did you log in again after the change to your `.bashrc`? The file is only sourced for _new_ shell sessions.

Comment: Yes, unquoted. It still does not work. I did login again. The error persisted.

Comment: Have you actually looked where the `javac` executable got installed? Try `find ~/jres -name javac`.

Comment: No. Thanks for asking. When I typed this command, there was no output or errors. The location ~/jres/java-8 was created using symlink of the JDK location at /usr/java/jres/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.272.b10-1.portable.jdk.el.x86_64, after I searched this JDK location, I found it in the bin folder.

Comment: Yes, resolved. Thank you @Kusalananda !

Comment: So, this means you unpacked the archive in `/usr` rather than in your home directory as the instructions specified?  Doing so would quite naturally mean having to adjust the pathnames shown in the installation notes.

Comment: Yes. Not unpacked in the home directory.